# how break loop inside another loop

Tags: c, loops, break

if there is 3 loop inside each other how could i break to upper level loop i mean:

there is

```
while (abc) {
    for (int dep =0 ; dep<b ; dep++)  {
         for (int jwe=0 ; jwe<g ; jwe++) {
             if (! (ef || hf) ) {
             //here is where i want to break to loop while
             //or in other purpose (other situation) i need 
             //to know how i could break to first loop  
             //i mean (for (int dep =0 ; dep< b ; dep++)
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Would somebody please help me , how after if , i could break to the while loop  , or how i could break to first loop "for" .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set the counter of the outer loop to a value such that it wont run again.

```
while (abc) {
    for (int dep =0 ; dep<b ; dep++)
    for (int jwe=0 ; jwe<g ; jwe++)
     if (! (ef || hf) ) {
         //here is where you want to break to the while-loop
         //abc = 0; here will make it exit the entire while as well
         dep = b; //in order to exit the first for-loop
         break;
     }
}
```

Comment: Aham, that's clever (and subject to break). +1.

Comment: very clever indeed,   thanks , this will break to first loop (For) am i right?  And if i want to break to loop while , then i have to write some thing like this                                                                 if (!(ef || hf)) {             dep =b; abc = 0; break }  am i right?

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the (rare) cases in which `goto` is the clearest construct:

```
while (abc) {
    for (int dep =0 ; dep<b ; dep++)  {
         for (int jwe=0 ; jwe<g ; jwe++) {
             if (! (ef || hf) ) {
                 // Do anything needed before leaving "in the middle"
                 goto out;
             }
         }
    }
}
out:
// Continue here
```

Make sure the indentation doesn't hide the label.

Answer (score 0):

Some languages (Java included) support breaking to labels:

```
outerLoop: // a label
while(true) {
   for(int i = 0; i < X; i++) {
      for(int j = 0; j < Y; j++) {
         // do stuff 
         break outerLoop; // go to your label
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem much better than a goto statement (which Java doesn't have though) ;)

Comment: @Cthulhu It pretty much is a goto, but it is a way to get directly to the outermost loop.

Comment: Thanks it's also good to know java feature about this subject , but the language is c , Anyway i learn a helpful tip from your comment too, Thanks

Comment: @Cthulhu: the problem with `goto` is not that control is transferred elsewhere in the function (this is true of all control structures from `if` on upwards). The problem with `goto` is that it subverts other structures. Breaking to a labelled loop *doesn't* subvert other structures, at least no more than `break` does inherently. Which is why it makes some sense to have that feature without having `goto` in general.

Answer (score 0):

```
int breakForLoop=0;
    int breakWhileLoop=0;
    while (abc) {

        for (int dep = 0;dep < b;dep++) {

            for (int jwe = 0;jwe < g; jwe++) {


                if (!(ef || hf)) {
                    breakForLoop=1;
                    breakWhileLoop=1;
                    break;

                }
            }
            if(breakForLoop==1){
                break;
            }
        }
        if( breakWhileLoop==1){
                break;
            }
    }
```

Comment: You can also use goto statement

Comment: you can also check for the break variable in the loop statement itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `int` variable, `int terminate = 0;` for example and place it in while loop along with your condition `while(true && terminate == 0)`. When you want to break outer loop, set the variable to `1` before breaking from the inner loops.

Answer (score 0):

```
continue_outer_loop = true;
while (abc) {

  for ( int i = 0; i < X && continue_outer_loop; i++) {
    for ( int j = 0; j < Y; j++ {

       if (defg) {
         continue_outer_loop = false;  // exit outer for loop
         break;                        // exit inner for loop
       }

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks , yeah , this is another valid (correct) solution for this subject , TBH that is came also to my mind  after reading other posts . Anyway thanks for sharing your thought. :D